# Chef - How to Mount LVM with UUID

Tags: linux, chef-infra, mount

I have the following after running blkid on RHEL:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_mongodb-lv_app: UUID="9b0b44f4-a167-43b9-a66a-972cb7777915" TYPE="xfs"
```

Using the Chef mount resource, I want to mount the LVM with the UUID, so I have something like this:

```
mount node['app_mount_dir'] do
  dump 1
  pass 2
  device node['/dev/mapper/vg_mongodb-lv_app']['app_uuid']
  device_type :uuid
  fstype node['fstype']
  options node['options']
  action [ :mount, :enable]
end
```

From my attributes file:

```
default["app_uuid"] = "9b0b44f4-a167-43b9-a66a-972cb7777915"
```

However, I'm getting an error when running chef-client:

```
 Device  does not exist
```

From compiled resource:

```
fsck_device "-"
```

So obviously the device, the way I entered it, cannot be located.

Is my syntax incorrect?  Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `default["app_uuid"] = "9b0b44f4-a167-43b9-a66a-972cb7777915"` in attributes you should use `device node["app_uuid"]` in resource call.

In addition, if you know the device name, you can use UUID from ohai instead of setting it by hand - `node["filesystem2"]["by_device"]["/dev/mapper/vg_mongodb-lv_app"]["uuid"]`.

(I assume you are using fairly recent Chef version)

Comment: Thanks Szymon. I forgot about using Ohai. Your input worked perfectly!  Much appreciated!